# How can I populate matrix array with different random numbers

Tags: javascript

I have a matrix of arrays and I want to populate each array with different random numbers, I've tried to use fill() method, but it set only one number for each array, while I want to set all different numbers. Here is the link on my [pen](https://codepen.io/MegaZef/pen/MdWbBK) and the code I've problem with:

```
let matrix = [];

function matrixItem() {
    let a = +prompt("How many arrays should matrix include?");
    let reg = /^\d+$/;
    if (reg.test(a) && (typeof (a)) != null && a != '' && a <= 10) {
      for (let i = 0; i < a; i++) {
        matrix.push((Array(Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1)
        /* problem is here */.fill(Math.round(Math.random() * 100))));
      }
      let sum = matrix.map(function (x) {
        return x.reduce(function (a, b) {
          return a + b;
        });
      });
      console.log(sum);
    } else matrixItem();
  }
matrixItem();
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The `fill()` method fills all the elements of an array with **a static value**. Use `Array.from` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Array#fill`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) takes a constant value and fills the array with this value.

For getting a dynamic array with random values, you could take [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) and map the random values.

```js
var array = Array.from(
        { length: Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1 },
        () => Math.round(Math.random() * 100)
    );

console.log(array);
```